# What is the mean of Xbar?

Tags: r

```
randomsamples5 <- expand.grid(Roll1 = sides, Roll2 = sides, Roll3 = sides,Roll4 = sides, Roll5 = sides)
View(randomsamples5)
Xbar <- apply(randomsamples5, 1, mean)
RandomSamplingValues5 <- cbind(randomsamples5, Xbar = Xbar)
View(RandomSamplingValues5)
View(RandomSamplingValues5)
library(MASS)   
Table5 <- fractions(xtabs(~Xbar)/7776)  
Table5
ProbabilityDistributionXbar5 <- data.frame(Table5) 
View(ProbabilityDistributionXbar5)
x11()
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ProbabilityDistributionXbar5, aes(x=Xbar,y=Freq)) + geom_segment(aes(x=Xbar,xend=Xbar,y=0,yend=Freq),color="red") + geom_point()
View(ProbabilityDistributionXbar5)
```

This is a Rstudio code that I did for rolling a die 5 times how would I calculate the mean of Xbar of the data?
What is the mean of Xbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either get the mean of `Xbar` directly from the sample space calculation like this:

```r
mean(RandomSamplingValues5$Xbar)
#> [1] 3.5
```

Or you can get it as a weighted sum of the probability distribution you calculated later on, like this:

```r
sum(as.numeric(as.character(ProbabilityDistributionXbar5$Xbar)) * 
  ProbabilityDistributionXbar5$Freq)
#> [1] 3.5
```